# Verificar si el caracter está repetido en el vector

Tags: c, array, programación-funcional

Hice un método para verficar si los caracteres ingresados están repetidos o no, `verificador()` el cual no me funciona, y no encuetro el error.

Aquí el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*CREAR 'N' CONJUNTOS (VECTORES), CON 'N' ELEMENTOS EN CADA VECTOR, Y LUEGO LLENARLOS CON CARACTERES QUE NO SE REPITAN EN EL MISMO VECTOR. */

bool verificador(int i, int j,char **matriz); //prototipo de funcion

int main ()
{
    system("color f4");

    char **matriz;  //Matriz Dinamica

    int vectores, elementos;

    int num; //Variable que le va a indicar al usuario en qué conjunto está.

        do //Utilizo un 'do-while' para validar el ingreso del tipo de dato.
        {       

            system("CLS");  
            printf("DIGITE EL NUMERO DE CONJUNTOS QUE DESEA CREAR (DEBE SER MAYOR A '0'): ");
        }
        while(!scanf("%d",&vectores)==1 || vectores==0);


        matriz = (char**)malloc(vectores*sizeof(char*)); //Reservando memoria, para el puntero 'matriz'.

        int CantidadElementos[vectores]; //Éste vector, me crea la cantidad de conjuntos(vectores) que hay en '**matriz',
                                        // para luego llenarlos con la cantidad de elementos de cada vector.

        for(int i=0; i<vectores; i++)
        {
            num=num+1; //Para indicarle al usuario en qué conjunto está posicionado.                
            do
            {       
                system("CLS");  
                printf("DIGITE LA CANTIDAD DE ELEMENTOS QUE DESEA INGRESAR EN EL CONJUNTO %d (DEBE SER MAYOR A '0'): ",num);
            }
            while(!scanf("%d",&elementos)==1 || elementos==0);


            CantidadElementos[i]=elementos; //Se guarda el numero de elementos del conjunto

            matriz[i]= (char*)malloc(elementos*sizeof(char)); //Reservando memoria, para el vector.

            for(int j=0; j<elementos;j++) //Llenando el vector.
            {
                fflush(stdin); //Liberar Memoria 
                    do
                        {       
                            system("CLS");  
                            printf("DIGITE LOS ELEMENTOS QUE QUIERE INGRESAR EN EL CONUNJUNTO %d (NO SE PUEDEN REPETIR): ",num);
                        }
                    while(!scanf("%c",&matriz[i][j])==1 || verificador(i,j,matriz)==true); //while(Verifica el tipo de dato ó si encuentra
                                                                                            //el valor repetido en el vector.

                    matriz[i][j]=toupper(matriz[i][j]); //Convertir el caracter ingresado en mayúscula.
            }
        }
        num=0; //inicializo nuevamente la variable que le indicara al usuario el numero del conjunto. 

        for(int a=0;a<vectores;a++) //Mostrar en Pantalla, caracteres ingresados.
        {
            num=num +1;
            printf("\nCONJUNTO Nº %d: \n", num);

            for(int j=0;j<CantidadElementos[a];j++)
            {
                printf("| %c | \t",matriz[a][j]);
            }

            printf("\n");
        }

    free(matriz); //Liberar memoria de la matriz dinamica.
    return 0;
}

bool verificador(int i, int j, char **matriz) //Verifica si el caracter ingresado se repite en el mismo vector
{
    int c;

    if(j==0) //Si 'j' es = 0, se da por entendido que es el primer ciclo de ingreso de datos, por lo tanto no hay
                                                                            // numeros anteriores para verificar.
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(j>0)
    {
        c=j-1; //Le resto '1' para que no compare la misma posicion, sino la anterior.
    }

    for(int columna=c;columna==0;columna--)
    {
        if(matriz[i][columna]==matriz[i][j])
        {
            return true; //si se encuentra el valor, regrese true
        }
    }
    return false; //si no lo encuentra , regrese falso.
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el motivo por el que no funciona? ¿Dice que todos son repetidos? ¿no detecta los repetidos? ¿comportamiento aleatorio? ¿te pide una pizza de unicornios cada vez que lo ejecutas?

Comment: @eferion El programa al introducir una letra debe verificar si está en el mismo vector donde se esta guardando, si existe esa letra, debe pedirme ingresar una letra diferente. El problema es que si yo  introduzco una letra  **A** que ya existe (para probar si hace bien la verficacion) ,me devuelve un valor false, lo que significa que no esta haciendo la comparacion debidamente, y la toma como si no existiese ese valor. Al imprimir los vectores me aparece: **|A| |A|**

Comment: por favor, edita la pregunta y añade lo que indicas via comentario. Si esperas que la gente se tenga que leer los comentarios para responderte perderás muchas respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De momento tu programa tiene un problema que no está relacionado con tu método `verificador()` (que no he depurado, pero parece que tampoco está haciendo bien su cometido), sino con la forma en que lees caracteres.

### El problema

Este es un problema en el que tarde o temprano acaba cayendo todo programador en C, y es que `scanf()` no "consume" los retornos de carro que aparecen tras un dato que hayas leído.

Así, por ejemplo, el pequeño fragmento de código:

```
char letra;
printf("Dame una letra: ");
scanf("%c", &letra);
```

de aspecto inofensivo, encierra una trampa. Típicamente el usuario ante esa pregunta pulsará una tecla en su teclado (por ejemplo `A`), pero no pasa nada aún, ya que la entrada es orientada a líneas y hasta que no pulse retorno de carro, nada es enviado al programa.

Así que tras la `A` el usuario pulsa retorno de carro. Entonces toda la línea que haya tecleado es enviada al programa y procesada por `scanf()`. Ya que éste usa `%c` se le está diciendo que lea sólo el primer carácter de lo que encuentre en el buffer de entrada. Éste será la letra `A`. El resto lo ignora. `scanf()` en este caso retornará 1 para indicar que ha procesado con éxito un token, y dejará en `&letra` la `A` que ha leido. Todo parece correcto, pero **en el buffer de entrada aún está el retorno de carro sin leer**.

Si tras el código anterior viene ahora esto:

```
char letra2;
printf("Dame otra letra: ");
scanf("%c", &letra2);
```

el usuario verá el mensaje invitándole a escribir, pero no tendrá oportunidad de teclear nada porque `scanf()` encontrará en el buffer de entrada el retorno de carro que estaba sin leer de antes, y lo leerá como un carácter, que asignará a `letra2` (que tendrá entonces el valor `\n`), y retornará también 1 pues ha tenido éxito en leer otro carácter.

Sólo que no es el comportamiento esperado. Querríamos que `scanf()` se detenga de nuevo hasta que el usuario teclee otra línea.

Por desgracia `fflush(stdin)` que tienes por ahí en tu programa no sirve para "limpiar" el buffer de entrada antes de leer algo más. La operación `fflush()` sólo puede hacerse sobre buffers de salida.

### Soluciones

La más sencilla es usar `" %c"` en lugar de `"%c"`. El espacio delante le dice a `scanf()` que "ignore todos los blancos" antes de leer el siguiente carácter. Se entiende por blanco un espacio blanco, un tabulador, o un retorno de carro. Mientras encuentre cualquiera de estos tres, lo ignorará e intentará leer el siguiente carácter.

Así pues, usando ese truco para la lectura del segundo carácter, el `\n` que estaba en el buffer de entrada será ignorado, `scanf()` intentará leer otro carácter más y como no hay más quedará esperando a que el usuario teclee más cosas. Es decir, el comportamiento esperado.

Otra solución es usar `scanf("%c%*c", &letra)` que dice a `scanf()` que lea un carácter (`%c`) y que lea también el siguiente pero sin guardarlo en ningún sitio, es decir, que lo descarte (`%*c`).

Este sería un ejemplo de la primera solución:

```
char letra;
char letra2;

printf("Dame una letra: ");
scanf(" %c", &letra);
printf("Dame otra letra: ");
scanf(" %c", &letra2);
printf("Letras tecleadas: |%c|, |%c|\n", letra, letra2);
```

Si el usuario ante la primera pregunta escribe `A` y pulsa retorno de carro, el siguiente `scanf()` descartará ese retorno de carro y esperará a la siguiente letra. Pero si el usuario ante la primera pregunta teclea `AB` y pulsa retorno de carro, entonces el primer `scanf()` leerá la `A`, y dejará la `B` (y el retorno de carro posterior) sin leer, por lo que el segundo `scanf()` no esperará nada y leerá la `B` (dejando otro retorno de carro sin leer). Esto no puede evitarse de forma sencilla.

## Tu código

Sustituye en tu código todos los `"%c"` por `" %c"` y al menos ya leerá correctamente la entrada del usuario.

Te dejo que continúes depurando la función `verificador()` pues, si su cometido era evitar que el usuario teclee caracteres repetidos, no está funcionando.

Comment: Oh! Gracias, Interesante lo que me comentas, lo implementaré. En cuanto a la función `Verificador()`, ya lo solucioné, estaba comparando una letra en  mayuscula y otra en minuscula (A==a), por eso nunca entraba en la condición.