# problema con loop infinito

Tags: c, while, bucles

necesito hacer un programa que solicita el sexo y la edad de un número de personas (se supone que termina al poner 'n' en sexo)...y luego dice cuantas mujeres y varones asistieron...además de intervalos de edad (cuantos hombres y mujeres de ciertas edades se registraron)...El punto es que luego de la primera iteración el programa pregunta el sexo...luego la edad...pero inmediatamente después vuelve a preguntar la edad sin pasar por el sexo...y no puedo salir de ahí salvo que fuerce la salida o ingrese 'n' muchas veces...

```
/* Se supone que ingrese el sexo (F/f/M/m) y la edad de cada persona y cuando se
   ingrese 'N' o 'n' en sexo...el programa debe indicar cuantas mujeres
   fueron registradas y cuantas de ellas tenían entre 22 y 25 años...
   en el caso de los hombres también se debe indicar cuantos se registraron
   y decir cuántos de elos tenían entre 18 y 30 años...*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int edad, nvar=0, ndam=0, nv1830=0, nd2225=0;
  char sexo;

  do
  {
    printf("Ingrese sexo (F/M)(0 si no hay nadie): ");
    scanf("%c", &sexo);
    printf("\nIngrese edad (0 si no hay nadie): ");
    scanf("%d", &edad);
    if(sexo=='f' || sexo=='F')
    {
      ndam++;
      if(edad>=22 && edad<=25)
      {
        nd2225++;
      }
    }
    else if(sexo=='m' || sexo=='M')
    {
      nvar++;
      if(edad>= 18 && edad<=30)
      {
        nv1830++;
      }
    }
    else if(sexo=='n' || sexo=='N')
    {
      printf("Asistieron %d damas a la fiesta.\n", ndam);
      printf("Damas con edades entre 22 y 25: %d\n", nd2225);
      printf("\nAsistieron %d varones a la fiesta.\n", nvar);
      printf("Varones con edades entre 18 y 30: %d\n", nv1830);
    }
  }
  while(sexo!='n' || sexo!= 'N');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola. Tu problea es que tu do while estará dentro hasta que seco! =N

Comment: Hola...honestamente no sé a qué te refieres con "seco! =N...te agradecería ser más específico...

Comment: ¿Qué valor de `sexo` hace que `(sexo != 'n' || sexo != 'N')` valga `false`?

Comment: Perdona. Edito. La condición de salida es que sexo debe ser igual a 'n' y 'N' al mismo tiempo cosa que es imposible. Revisa esa tabla de la verdad. Saludos

Comment: lo limité solo a letras minusculas...para tener una sola opción...sin exito...me preocupa el hecho de que se salte el `scanf("%d", &sexo);` tras la segunda iteración..

Comment: @Dr.Haus Es un problema típico cuando lees un carácter con `"%c"` tras haber leido un entero con `"%d"`. Arréglalo poniendo un espacio en la cadena de formato, así: `" %c"`. La explicación del por qué la dí hace tiempo en otra respuesta, que estoy buscando. Te pongo el enlace cuando la encuentre.

Comment: @abulafia Funcionó...supongo que eso hacía que `sexo` nunca cambiara de valor...por eso se repetía...gracias...de momento va bien...ahora voy a ver si hace bien los conteos...

Comment: @Dr.Haus Lo encontré: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158308/7123 Aquí explico el por qué de ese comportamiento.

Comment: @abulafia muy buena tu explicación...y funciona bien ahora...muchas gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La interfaz de `scanf` es inteligente hasta cierto punto.

Si te fijas verás que la ejecución no abandona `scanf` hasta que no introduces un salto de línea. Pues bien, `scanf` suele eliminar este salto de línea en numerosas ocasiones sin que tu seas consciente de ello, como por ejemplo en tu código:

```
printf("Ingrese sexo (F/M)(0 si no hay nadie): ");
scanf("%c", &sexo);
printf("\nIngrese edad (0 si no hay nadie): ");
scanf("%d", &edad); // <<---
```

El segundo `scanf` está eliminando el salto de línea que el usuario ha almacenado en el buffer de entrada al introducir el sexo y tu no has tenido que hacer nada específico para que esto suceda.

Sin embargo, al introducir la edad en el buffer de entrada se queda otro salto de línea y aquí ya si empiezan los problemas. `scanf` no va a eliminar el salto de línea cuando se le pide leer un caracter.

Sin embargo sí que podemos ignorar este salto de línea añadiendo un espacio antes de `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c",&sexo);
```

Otra opción pasa por descartar el salto de línea después de leer la edad:

```
scanf("%d", &edad);
getchar(); // Descartamos el salto de línea
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Ingrese sexo (F/M)(0 si no hay nadie): ");
scanf("%c", &sexo);
printf("\nIngrese edad (0 si no hay nadie): ");
scanf("%d", &edad);
```

Cuando realizas lo anterior, al ser el llamado por primera vez el `scanf` este espera ha que se tecle algo y al hacerlo se hace un salto de línea que queda almacenado en un buffer. para solucionarlo solo debes limpiarlo con `fflush(stdin);` tu codigo quedaria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int edad, nvar=0, ndam=0, nv1830=0, nd2225=0;
  char sexo;

  do
  {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese sexo (F/M)(0 si no hay nadie): ");
    scanf("%c", &sexo);
    printf("\nIngrese edad (0 si no hay nadie): ");
    scanf("%d", &edad);
    if(sexo=='f' || sexo=='F')
    {
      ndam++;
      if(edad>=22 && edad<=25)
      {
        nd2225++;
      }
    }
    else if(sexo=='m' || sexo=='M')
    {
      nvar++;
      if(edad>= 18 && edad<=30)
      {
        nv1830++;
      }
    }
    else if(sexo=='n' || sexo=='N')
    {
      printf("Asistieron %d damas a la fiesta.\n", ndam);
      printf("Damas con edades entre 22 y 25: %d\n", nd2225);
      printf("\nAsistieron %d varones a la fiesta.\n", nvar);
      printf("Varones con edades entre 18 y 30: %d\n", nv1830);
    }
  }
  while(sexo!='n' || sexo!= 'N');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte...pero ya me resolvieron el problema...además...lo acabo de probar y no funciona...lo siento...gracias de todos modos...

Comment: yo lo probe y funciona perfecto

Comment: curioso...ahora el problema puede ser un poco más externo...tal vez simplemente error mío...en qué estás?..yo estoy en linux...aunque no creo que tenga mucho que ver...

Comment: Utilizo Windows, Codeblock con Mingw

Comment: pero ya está resuelto...revisa los comentarios...de hecho @abulafia explica que no funciona `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: no lo he probado en windows...

Comment: Por favor... dejad de recomendar el uso de `fflush(stdin)`, por favor... se trata de  **comportamiento indefinido**.